# Parallelizing a nested loop in Rust

Tags: rust, parallel-processing

I have this simple nested loop:

```
pub fn update_gravity_physics(
    bodies: &mut Vec<Box<dyn PhysObj>>,
) {
    for i in 0..bodies.len() {
        for j in i+1..bodies.len() {
            let (fx, fy): (f32, f32) = calculate_gravity(&*bodies[i], &*bodies[j]);
            bodies[i].add_vector((fx, fy));
            bodies[j].add_vector((-fx, -fy));
        }
    }
}
```

which works just fine, but I think I want to optimize it via parallelization. I still feel pretty new to Rust, so I don't really have a ton of experience with this kinda thing.

I have tried some approaches with rayon (which I am not very comfortable with), but I run into issues because I am mutating the bodies, even though the changes I make don't really affect any of the calculations I want to do in parallel (adding the force vectors); alas rust's memory safety stuff doesn't seem to like it. I'd prefer avoiding arc mutex things if possible, as I have other fns that rely on my `Vec<Box<dyn PhysObj>>`.

Comment: Instead of mutating, you may want to compute a whole new output from the given immutable input(s).

Comment: What if while you're calculating the gravity for two objects, one of them will change? Rust has saved you here. _Before_ you try to code, _think_ how you are going to solve this problem.

Comment: During each timestep, all of the force vectors acting upon each body are calculated, after which they are summed into a final force vector [for each body], which is used to update the object's acceleration. The snippet of code I shared is only calculating the pairwise force of gravity between objects - and gravity will not always be the only force. I'm trying to say the objects can't change position while the various force vectors are being calculated because it operates in discrete time steps.

Comment: Ok. So you are mutating different fields than those you read (my misunderstanding came due to the lack of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which you should _always_ provide, please do). Still, there is a risk of data race when updating the positions of two bodies in parallel. You can solve this by making the position atomic.